# Encapsulation and const issues

Tags: c++, constants

I have a problem in a c++ assignment that cannot be solved. Lets say this - the program works only if the membervariable (a pointer to an char-array) i public. But according to the rules it must be private and one should be able to access it through a public member-method.

Here is the definitions:

```
private:
   char* _strPtr();
   int _strLen;
public:
   const char* getString();
```

---

```
const char* String::getString() {
   return _strPtr;
 }
```

And here in an overloaded member-function the problem arises

```
 const String operator+(const String string, const char *ch) {

   String temp;
   strcpy(temp.getString, string.getString());
   strcat(string.getString(), ch);

return temp;

 }
```

I get error-messages such as

```
 invalid arguments Candidates are ; unsigned int strlen(const char *)
 invalid arguments Candidates are ; const char* getString()
```

I cannot see how this could be solved. I have really tried with everything. Would be glad if someone could come with good tips.

As - I said in th beginning - the program works, but after encapsulating the membervariable and putting a const ahead of the function - it doesn't work any more.

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `temp.getString()` instead of `temp.getString`?

Comment: @keyser - yes, I changed the code - but the problem persists

Comment: Same error? It didn't match the candidate `const char* getString()` now?

Comment: See [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) for good ideas on how to implement `operator +` in terms of a member `operator +=`.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `char* _strPtr();`, which is the definition of a function returning a `char*`. Probably what you meant was to define `char* _strPtr;`